# SQL: Single query to find the combined survival percentage. (Titanic dataset)

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4iBP.png)
I need to write a single query to find the combined survival percentage of males over >=50 and women over >=40.

My code,

```
df_combined_surv = sqldf("SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN Sex = 'male' AND Age >= 50 AND Survived = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Sex = 'female' AND Age >= 40 AND Survived = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / (SUM(CASE WHEN Sex = 'male' AND Age >= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Sex = 'female' AND Age >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS SurvivalPercentage FROM df_titanic")

df_combined_surv.head()
```

Keep gives 0 for some reasons, but the correct answer is approx. 0.457143.

Please help me with the code, and the point is it should be a "single query".

FYI,

```
df_combined_surv1 = sqldf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df_titanic WHERE CASE WHEN ((Sex = 'male' AND Age >= 50 AND Survived = 1) OR (Sex = 'female' AND Age >= 40 AND Survived = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
                          
df_combined_surv2 = sqldf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df_titanic WHERE CASE WHEN ((Sex = 'male' AND Age >= 50) OR (Sex = 'female' AND Age >= 40)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END") 
 
df_combined_surv1 / df_combined_surv2
```

This gives the correct answer, but it's in multiple queries. I'm just having trouble when combining these codes in a single query.

Comment: I would remove the SUM's and just leave the CASE portions with a 1 or 0, and then manually investigate ones that are "wrong" - the most common culprit here is that 'male' is actually 'Male', or has spaces in the front, or Survived is text and not number, so it would be ='1' instead of =1.

Comment: Thank you! I actually have tried investigating each portions, but all of the figures were correct, so I think the problem is from when I combined in a single query, or the SELECT function or the /  (;division) part..  Can you please help me with this, by actually showing me the right code?

Comment: Hmm, it looks correct to me.  Have you tried separating the numerator from the denominator (instead of the / sign, use a comma and make it a separate column) - do those counts add up correctly? I'm wondering if perhaps your notebook is rounding the answer to 0. If that is the case, try using 1.00000 and 0.0000 instead of 1 and 0 in the case statements

Comment: CORRECT. It was just keep rounding it up. THANK YOU MAN.